# How to increase the size of fanpage?

Tags: facebook-page

I have started developing `facebook fanpages` using `HTML` and `CSS`. The size of my first page was about 800*900 and it had sidebars. I had to resize it to `499` by `699` to work without the sidebars. I have seen fan pages whose height is quite larger than the size 500 but no sidebar appears. [Here](http://www.facebook.com/BobMarley?sk=app_11007063052) is an example. Can anyone please explain how do they achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that will work... put before `</head>` tag on each page of your fanpages html code!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
}
function sizeChangeCallback() {
    FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
</script>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Should auto extend FB canvas height of page! Worked on my FB fanpage! :) Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

The width of a Facebook Page Tab is always limited and can not be extended. The height is expandable.

Answer (score 1):

Only 520px is visible. You can make scrolls invisible in CSS, but you can't make page more than 520px.
 http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: Can you help out how to remove the scrolls?

Comment: Put div block with 520 width and set overflow:hidden; http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Here is my page. http://technology-arena.com/MaiAbdulQadirHoon.html I have used this on http://www.facebook.com/umarctn1?sk=app_209227672472537 and it does not show it fully. The width is 499 and the height as is large